# WSO2 Governance is sending email validation e-mails but not for subscriptions

Tags: email, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Set up WSO2 governance.  Set up axis2.xml so that when setting up an e-mail subscription to a collection it sends a validate e-mail request e-mail fine.  But the subscription is never firing... Tried all events, Create child, update, create LC.

Any help?

Nothing in the log files to say it failed to send.... or that is even tried.

One thing to note is that this subscription is on a custom artifact type's storage collection/

Comment: what is the G Reg version you are using? And also what is the notification type (is it email ?)

Comment: Latest of the website 4.5.2 and yes it was an email notification type.

Comment: I was able to get the notifications for services as well as RXTs. can you check are there notifications available in /_system/governance/event/topics/registry/notifications

Comment: There is a folder structure under here as per link 1 [link](http://imgur.com/EC4iz)  And the notification set up is here [link](http://imgur.com/97mPu)

Comment: Could you please check with update as event and frequency as none for email subscription. I am worried as it works for me and as you are not getting any errors :(

Comment: Thanks it works now.  The issue looks to be that I was setting a frequency and not using 'none'  Do you know when frequency should be used?  Would have been nice for the documentation to note this....  Cheers again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the notification documentation [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance452/Adding+a+Subscription). Use 'none' if you need instance or else there are frequencies like hourly, weekly etc.

Comment: This is correct but the documentation should be updated to include the line 'Use 'none' if you need instance or else there are frequencies like hourly, weekly etc'